# How to compare 2 strings with various combinations in the middle of them in c#

Tags: c#, string, compare

I'm searching for the "best" way to implement a custom way to compare 2 strings.
With "best" meaning: efficient, easy to use and easy to understand.

We have some codes with the following format: "XX 0123 4567" where XX are 2 alpha-numeric characters and '0123 4567' are hexa-decimal digits.

In our integration tests we expect some strings like:
"This is a code SZ 0467 4FA1 in a middle of a sentence"

Unfortunately, we have several ways to display codes to end-user (requirement).
These codes might be displayed as

- XY 1A2B 3C4E (usually)
- XY1A2B3C4E (often)
- XY-1A2B-3C4E (rarely)
- xy 1a2b 3c4e (1 time)
- ... others ?

Assuming that we really don't care how the code is displayed and we don't want to bother changing tests if the final U.I. changes the code display we would like to be able to write something like this

```
var actual = GetTheActualValue();
var expected = $@"This is a code SZ 0467 4FA1 in a middle of a sentence"
var areEquals = // The magic comparison stands here
```

Our current idea is to "mark" the code part in expected as "to be interpolated"

```
var expected = $@"This is a code {{SZ 0467 4FA1}} in a middle of a sentence"
```

With our comparer understanding that what is betwen { and } is a code that can be written in any allowed form

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Or any other idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the string with regex and then use your custom comparer:

```
var extracted = Regex.Match(
    expected,
    @"\b[A-Z0-9]{2}[- ]?[0-9A-F]{4}[- ]?[0-9A-F]{4}\b",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Or, if your input text always the one you provided:

```
var extracted = Regex
    .Match(
        expected,
        @"This is a code (.+?) in a middle of a sentence",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Groups[1]
    .Value;
```

Comment: Beside the fact that Regexes are not considered as "easy to read" by some of our team members, I still have the comparison problem. Your sample give me a way to extract our codes from the "expected" string, I can do the same from the "actual" string and compare both. But I still need to compare that the remaining of the strings. (and we have hundreds distinct "expected" and, of course, some might contain up to 10 "codes")

Comment: @user2563824 the second example that I posted is very eady to understand. The easiest way to compare after the extraction is to normalize: replace all unwanted characters by empty strings and convert all to upper case.